# Use Gmail API and Firebase's database of another app in one iOS application

Tags: ios, firebase, gmail, firebase-realtime-database, gmail-api

In my app I use Firebase's database (which used by another my app) and GMail api. Both of these services require certain Client ID which must be on GoogleService-Info.plist file. So, if I use Gmail's client id, the firebase's app won't work. Is that possible to define client id which you want for this services?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of options:

If you go to the [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com) > *Auth* > *Sign In Method*, and select *Google* you can whitelist the client ID you are using for your gmail API access. This will allow you to use the client ID for gmail with sign in (either by specifying the client ID to `GIDSignIn` directly, or by manually updating it in the `GoogleService-Info.plist`), and use the credential from that Sign In with the `FirebaseAuth` APIs.

The other option is just to enable your Firebase project for gmail API access. Any Firebase project is also a Google project, so you can go to the [Google Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com) and find the Firebase project you created, then enable the gmail API as you did before. The down side of this is that your users that had previously signed in on your Google project will have to sign in again to your Firebase project to grant access to their resources.

Comment: According to the first option I should just paste CLIENT_ID from Xcode project into Google whitelist in FB console to make my user's database (from Authentication section) visible for my app that uses Gmail API, right?

Comment: could you please tell me the http method using which I can refresh access token?

Comment: On the device, refresh should happen automatically. On the server, see the REST tab on https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#offline

Comment: thanks Ian. As far as I understood, I can use 'refresh_token' forever or I need to refresh it like access_token after about 30 minutes?

Comment: is that possible to get client_secret for iOS app?